# Covariant derivative of four-position

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, differentiation, vector-fields, covariance

May someone confirm or deny that covariant derivative of four-position is just metric tensor?

I mean:
$\nabla_{\gamma}X_{\alpha} = g_{\gamma \alpha}$

When I try to rewrite it with base vectors it is
$\nabla_{\gamma}X_{\alpha} = \frac{\partial x_{\alpha} \vec{g}^{\alpha}}{\partial q_{\gamma}} =  \frac{\partial x_{\alpha}}{\partial q_{\gamma}} \vec{g}^{\alpha} + x_{\alpha} \frac{\partial \vec{g}^{\alpha}}{\partial q_{\gamma}}$

Does above two parts of equation sum to metric tensor?

Comment: $X_\mu$ is not a tensor or a tensor density. Its covariant derivative is not defined at all.

Answer (score 2):

In general relativity, we don't equip spacetime itself with a vector space structure, which means that the "four-position" is not a four-vector.  As a result, the object $x_\mu$ whose components are given by $x_{\mu}=g_{\mu \nu} x^\nu$ is not a covector.  One can show this by its transformation properties.

If we change coordinate systems from $x$ to $y$, then 
$$g_{\mu\nu}^{(x)} \rightarrow g^{(y)}_{\mu \nu} = \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial y^\mu} \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial y^\nu}g^{(x)}_{\alpha\beta}$$
$$x^{\nu}\rightarrow y^\nu$$

and so

$$x_\mu = g^{(x)}_{\mu \nu}x^\nu \rightarrow g^{(y)}_{\mu \nu}y^\nu =  \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial y^\mu} \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial y^\nu}g^{(x)}_{\alpha\beta} y^\nu = \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial y^\mu}g^{(x)}_{\alpha \beta}  \left(\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial y^\nu} y^\nu \right)$$

If this object were a covector, it would transform as
$$x_\mu \rightarrow y_\mu = \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial y^\mu} x_\alpha = \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial y^\mu} g^{(x)}_{\alpha\beta} x^\beta$$

Comparing this to what we found above, this is only true if
$$\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial y^\nu}y^\nu = x^\beta$$
i.e. if the coordinate transformation is *linear*.  Since coordinate transformations are, in general, **not** linear, then this equality does not hold, and $x_\nu$ are not the components of a covector.

Since covariant derivatives are defined by their actions on tensor fields (scalar fields, vector fields, etc), then we're dead in the water - the collection of symbols

$$\nabla_\gamma x_\alpha$$

does not correspond to a well-defined object.

Comment: If the transformation is linear, then it's tensor by definition. A tensor transforms as a  multilinear object. The covariant derivative of a $(r,s)$ tensor generates a $(r,s+1)$ tensor. The $X_{\alpha}$  is a $(0,1)$ tensor and becomes a $(0,2)$ tensor  - it's just not a metric tensor - and the OP's calculation of the covariant derivation of a $(0,1)$ tensor is wrong.

Comment: @CinaedSimson I believe you are missing the point that I made - $x_\mu$ are not the components of a tensor *at all*.  The transformation whose linearity (or lack thereof) I refer to in my answer is a general coordinate transformation, not the action of a tensor.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, 4-position is not a vector, so it does not have a covariant derivative. Describing it as a vector seems to assume Minkowski metric, in which case the covariant derivative is simply the partial derivative.

We do have, in curved spacetime and using general coordinates, for partial derivatives,

$$x^i_{,j} = {\partial x^i \over \partial x^j} = g^i_j $$

$$x_{i,j} =   g_{ij} $$

Comment: Quick question, is the 4-position a Lorentz tensor?

Comment: A vector is a particular case of a tensor. If it has just one index and is not a vector, then it is not a tensor; similarly, if it is a vector then it is a tensor. 4-position can only be described as a vector in Minkowski spacetime. In curved spacetime, we can still differentiate 4-position (using partial derivatives as in the answer) and the result is the metric tensor.